# How to install VS2013 extension package in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, vsix

I have created a VS2013 extension and now I want to install it in VS2012 as well. I [read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696828.aspx) that I should edit the vsixmanifest and add the InstallationTarget, so I did. I have VS2102 Premium and VS2013 Ultimate installed. Here is the xml I added to the manifest:

```
  <Installation InstalledByMsi="false">
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[11.0,12.0)" />
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" Version="[11.0,12.0)"  />
  </Installation>
```

Still, when I double click the vsix file to install it, it lists up just VS2013.

Comment: The breaking change in VS2013 is [described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/08/08/update-for-extension-authors-vsix-manifest-version-ranges.aspx).

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something. I built the extension in debug, and in the Debug folder, I have the vsix file and the vsixmanifest file. In the latter I am changing the InstallationTagerget, but it still does not show the VS2012 option. I tried ranges:
 <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[11.0, 12.0]" />
  <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" Version="[11.0, 12.0]" />
I also tried on separate lines:
 <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" Version="11.0" />
<InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Premium" Version="12.0" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed my VS2013 vsix to support VS2012 too, this is the resulted file:

```
<Installation InstalledByMsi="false">
    <InstallationTarget Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" Version="[12.0]" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[11.0,13.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
</Installation>
```

If I opened my VS2013 vsix, it now supports

[image]

both of these.

I suspect if that doesn't work for you, you might suffer some weird cache anomaly from previous installations. You should confirm that it indeed does work for other fresh computers.

The other alternative I see that you're doing things in wrong order.

The correct order would be: modify the manifest (source.extension.manifest file) in visual studio, build the project. Once *.vsix file is produced, the manifest file has no longer any effect. The manifest is embedded in *.vsix file

Comment: I did test that on another machine, but still it did not work. Perhaps I should upload the project somewhere?

Comment: Yeah, if you can make it so that it will be easily compileable in vs2013, I'll take quick look.

Comment: Here you are, a plain project with a menu item and your code in it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4z8Bw-7hU0aLUlEeWhnWmsxaGM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: checho: That doesn't help. It's just an output of debug folder where manifest file doesn't have even my code in it, unless I am missing something.

Comment: Here is the project as well: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4z8Bw-7hU0aUFM4Y1I1WkZQeDA/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Worked fine for me. Sounds like a potentially broken VS2013 install. None of your attached vsixmanifests has actually included the relevant informatino for it to show VS2012. Was that intentional?

Comment: It is rather strange that it works on your end. You have just added the suggested targets to the manifest file correct? I have updated the manifest file in the zip with the manifest file I use. What I am doing is to build the project, edit the built manifest file and add these lines in the <Installation> group.

Comment: The correct order would be: modify the manifest (**source.extension.manifest** file) in visual studio, build the project. Once *.vsix file is produced, **the manifest file has no longer any effect.** The manifest is embedded in *.vsix file.

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much! I would suggest that you add this information to your answer to make it even better.